# Selenium EventFiringWebDriver in page object model and refactored

Tags: selenium, java, logs

I'm struggling with this one, how to implement EventFiringWebDriver (e_driver) without having a lot of repetitive code.

As I'm understanding it, in order to capture finding elements and acting on them, the same registered EventFiringWebDriver must be used. This seems to leave two options.

a) In our WebElement getter methods, DON'T unregister the e_driver.
b) Create both getter and setter methods, both using e_driver.

Ex a)

```
public WebElement usernameField(){
        e_driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
        LoginPageListener1 = new EventListener();
        e_driver.register(LoginPageListener1);
        WebElement element = e_driver.findElement(By.name(USERNAME_FIELD_BY_NAME));
        //e_driver.unregister(LoginPageListener1);
        return element;
    }
```

Ex b)

```
public WebElement usernameField(){
        e_driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
        LoginPageListener1 = new EventListener();
        e_driver.register(LoginPageListener1);
        WebElement element = e_driver.findElement(By.name(USERNAME_FIELD_BY_NAME));
        e_driver.unregister(LoginPageListener1);
        return element;
    }

    public void fillUsernameField(String input){
        e_driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
        LoginPageListener1 = new EventListener();
        e_driver.register(LoginPageListener1);
        WebElement element = e_driver.findElement(By.name(PASSWORD_FIELD_BY_NAME));
        element.sendKeys(input);
        e_driver.unregister(LoginPageListener1);
    }
```

Lastly, I tried simplifying the WebElement getter method so that there isn't so much repetition, but I'm not sure about this solution.

```
public WebElement eDriverFindElement(String method, String locator){
        e_driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
        eventListener = new EventListener();
        e_driver.register(eventListener);
        WebElement element = null;
        if (method.equals("name")){
            element =  e_driver.findElement(By.name(locator));
        } else if (method.equals("id")){
            element =  e_driver.findElement(By.id(locator));
        }
        //e_driver.unregister(LoginPageListener1);   // <<--- Leaving this off to see if this allows activity capture of actions after finding element
        return element;
    }
```

**EDIT**
A third option I'm trying is to add the code to instantiate the EventFiringWebDriver and register it to the page class constructor.  Still, this method involves NOT unregistering, so I'm not sure if that will lead to any problems.

Ex c)

```
//Constructor
    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) throws Exception {
        this.driver = driver;
        e_driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);
        LoginPageListener1 = new EventListener();
        e_driver.register(LoginPageListener1);
    }

public WebElement usernameField(){          
        return e_driver.findElement(By.name(USERNAME_FIELD_BY_NAME));
    }

    public WebElement passwordField(){            
        return e_driver.findElement(By.name(PASSWORD_FIELD_BY_NAME));
    }

    public WebElement loginButton(){            
        return e_driver.findElement(By.name(LOGIN_BUTTON_BY_NAME));
    }
```